# Proving $Y$ such that $Y \cap B = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations, equivalence-relations

I have been solving this problem from Velleman's `How to prove` book:

> Suppose $B \subseteq A$ and define a relation $R$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$
>    as follows:
>
> $R = \{(X,Y) \in \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A) \mid
>  (X \Delta Y) \subseteq B\}$
>
> a) Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{P}(A)$.
>
> b) Prove that for every $X \in
>  \mathcal{P}(A)$ there is exactly one $Y \in [X]_R$ such that $Y \cap B
>  = \emptyset$

Now I have proved the first part of the question. But I'm stuck in the
second part. I cannot find any existential example for $Y$ for which
$Y \cap B = \emptyset$. Any pointers on how to solve it ?

Comment: Something is strange here... To me, there is a sense only if $X\subset B$. Moreover, $Y\in [X]\iff [X]=[Y]$ and thus $X/_R=\{[\emptyset]\}$, therefore the only class would be $[\emptyset]$... I probably didn't understand the exercise...

Comment: What exercise/chapter is this?

Comment: @Surb Sorry, There was a typo. It was $\mathbb{P}(A) \times \mathbb{P}(A)$.

Comment: @coldnumber  Chapter 4, section 6, question 14.

Answer (score 1):

First try proving the statement for $X \in \mathcal{P}(B)$, where there's a fairly obvious candidate for $Y$. Then see if you can generalize.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $X\Delta Y\subseteq B,$ then both $X\setminus Y$ and $Y\setminus X$ must be subsets of $B.$ If $Y$ is disjoint from $B,$ it follows that $Y\setminus X=\emptyset,$ which happens if and only if $Y\subseteq X.$

Hence, we need a subset $Y$ of $X$ such that $X\setminus Y\subseteq B$ and $Y\cap B=\emptyset.$ Can you take it from there? (Try playing with some examples on Venn diagrams, say with $A$ a particular small finite set, and with $X$ and $B$ as subsets of $A.$ Once you've set up the Venn diagram, see if you can figure out what $Y$ is, in terms of $X$ and $B$. Once you've got the idea, try to generalize the argument. If you're still stuck, feel free to let me know what you're having trouble with, and I'll see what I can do to extricate you.)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not able to come up after that. Also, how does it follow that $Y \subseteq X$ from the fact that $Y$ is disjoint from $B$. One could argue that may be $Y \setminus X$ is always $\emptyset$.

Comment: What can we conclude about *every* element of $Y$ from the fact that $Y\setminus X=\emptyset$?